# Over current AND reverse polarity protection using a MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet, protection, circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

Our lecturer posed us this problem. I just can't get it solved.

Design a circuit using a MOSFET which provides reverse polarity protection and ALSO over current protection. Over current protection should activate when current through a load is more than 2A.

Designing reverse polarity protection is easy, adding the over current protection... I can't get it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a big hint. You will need more than one MOSFET to perform both functions (assuming you wish to block reverse polarity inputs) since the body diode precludes using a MOSFET that blocks reverse polarity from being used to limit current.

Comment: I've been faffing around with two MOSFETs (both P and N type) in a single circuit for almost the entire day though and still can't get to grips with it.

Comment: A small current sense R with say 50mV drop can be used with some Vref to compare and drive the output FET which has suitable low RdsOn.  Reverse protection uses another FET.

Comment: I figured that if I used a 1ohm resistor, and a voltage source ramping up from 0-3V (I know my polarity protection works), I would want the second MOSFET to become an open circuit when the input voltage reaches 2V (creating the 2A current through the load). Selecting a P-type made sense to me as it is normally closed between source and drain. Where to connect the source and gate is the issue I have not solved in an entire day haha. I used a Pfet with a threshold voltage of -2V.

Comment: You can do it with only a NMOS but it will require a boosted gate voltage, via charge pump for example.

Comment: Try two back-to-back N-channel. If you're completely stuck peek at LTC's hot swap controllers.

Comment: @peufeu A typical commercial MOSFET can only block in one direction regardless of *what* you do to the gate. The body diode will conduct in the other direction at best. So if you want to block negative inputs it will conduct (modulo a diode drop) in the other direction and vice-versa. If you're willing to invoke a fuse + shunt diode you (maybe) don't need to block reverse voltages but I don't think that's in the spirit of the problem statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "spirit of the problem" is...